# Can't override CMemFile::GrowFile

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, overriding

I have a class derived from CMemFile called TempMemFile.  I need to but can't override the Growfile method in TempMemFile.

When I hand write the GrowFile method in my derived class (TempMemFile) it is never called and in class view when I click on my TempMemFile > Properties > Overrides the Growfile and other methods are not listed here.  In fact only 3 methods are listed as override-able Assert, Dump & Serialize. MSDN specifically states that this method can be overridden. Am I missing something?

Implementation / Declaration

```
// TempMemFile.h

class CTempMemFile : public CMemFile

    {

    public:
        CTempMemFile(void);
        ~CTempMemFile(void);
        DWORD Begin(void);

    private:      
      void GrowFile(SIZE_T dwNewLen);  // override

    };

// TempMemFile.cpp

CTempMemFile::CTempMemFile(void) : CMemFile

    {   

    }

CTempMemFile::~TempMemFile(void)
    {

    }


void GrowFile(SIZE_T dwNewLen)

{

// This function is never called but CMemFile::Growfile always is verified on the callstack

}
```

Comment: What do your declaration and invocation look like?

Comment: // TempMemFile.h

class CTempMemFile : public CMemFile
    
    {

    public:
        CTempMemFile(void);
        ~CTempMemFile(void);
        DWORD Begin(void);

         
       
    private:
    
      void GrowFile(SIZE_T dwNewLen);  // override
        
    };



// TempMemFile.cpp

CTempMemFile::CTempMemFile(void) : CMemFile
        
    {   
    
    }

CTempMemFile::~TempMemFile(void)
    {
 
    }


void GrowFile(SIZE_T dwNewLen)

{

// This function is never called but CMemFile::Growfile always is verified on the callstack


}

Comment: I have updated the original Q with the info your requested.

Comment: Can you show the context GrowFile is called from?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GrowFile` implementation is for a global function called `GrowFile`.  You need `CTempMemFile::` in front of the implementation.

```
void CTempMemFile::GrowFile(SITE_T dwNewLen)
{
}
```

Comment: Done that. Still exactly the Same.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that the visibility of your override method matches the declaration of the base class:

```
private:      
  void GrowFile(SIZE_T dwNewLen);  // override
```

is incorrect

Should be `public` or `protected` (whatever `CMemFile::GrowFile` declares it as).

Comment: Done that. Still exactly the Same.

Comment: I took a peek at CMemFile and GrowFile is protected. This implies that it is called by the base class rather than called by a consumer. Do you know under what circumstances that base class needs to call GrowFile and are you sure that you are causing those circumstances? It could just be that this ptoected method is never being called.